# ChangeBackground of TableLayout with xml file when I click on a button on the same layout

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created a linearlayout having 2 table layouts. In the first table I have a button. Now I want to display in the second table layout edittext and views that I have written in another XML file when I click on the button. Not the whole layout, only the second tablelayout will show the XML contents. Please help me with some sample code.

```
   />
   <View
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="1dip"
       android:background="#000000"

       />
   <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"

    />


<TableLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
       <TableLayout 
       android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
       android:stretchColumns="1"
       android:layout_weight="0.5"
        >
```

```
       </TableLayout>
       <TableLayout 
       android:id="@+id/change"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:stretchColumns="1"
       android:layout_weight="1">

       </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Now I want to set this XML file when I click on the button on the (TableLayout-android:id="@+id/change" )

Answer (score 0):

Here I place two Table layout in single layout and assign id to them in first Table layout I place Button and second Table layout i place Edit text with View.In program I remove the second Table layout. When we click on button then I remove the First Table layout and add second Table layout to show the Edit text and view in same layout without changing the activity.

code:

public class tabletext extends Activity 
{
    LinearLayout linear;
    TableLayout table1;
    TableLayout table2;
    Button bt;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        table1=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1);
         table2=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table2);
         bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         linear.removeView(table2);

```
     bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             linear.removeView(table1);
             linear.addView(table2);
        }
    });
}
```

}